# Определение разрядности, ip и mac адреса в label

Tags: c#, ip

День добрый, гуру.

Есть вопросик, как на C#, WinForm, сделать определение сабжа?

Вывод в консоль понятен, но как это вклеить в label, дабы при запуске программы информация просто выводилась как текст, не очень понятно.

Заранее, благодарю за ответ.

Comment: так у вас проблема с получением данных или их выводом в label?

Comment: И с тем и с другим. Т.е в консоль я получаю данные по ip, но мас адрес одни нули, а с выводом в лейбл вообще ничего не получилось

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MAC-адрес:

```
public string GetMACAddress()
{
    ManagementObjectSearcher objMOS = new ManagementObjectSearcher("Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration");
    ManagementObjectCollection objMOC = objMOS.Get();
    string MACAddress = String.Empty;
    foreach (ManagementObject objMO in objMOC)
    {
        if (MACAddress == String.Empty)   
        {
            MACAddress = objMO["MacAddress"].ToString();
        }
        objMO.Dispose();
    }
    MACAddress = MACAddress.Replace(":", "");
    return MACAddress;
}
```

Вывод в label - в конструкторе формы напишите

```
label1.Text = (ваши_данные);
```

Answer (score 1):

Получить IP можно разными способами, например:

```
WebClient webclient = new WebClient();
string ip = webclient.DownloadString("http://checkip.dyndns.com/");
ip = ip.Substring("<html><head><title>Current IP Check</title></head><body>Current IP Address: ".Length).Replace("</body></html>","");//Вытащить можно и по-другому
label1.Text = ip;
```